# How to make a python script run forever online?

Tags: python, web-services, monitoring, network-monitoring

I Have a python script that monitors a website, and I want it to send me a notification when some particular change happens to the website.
My question is how can I make that Python script runs for ever in some place else (Not my machine, because I want it to send me a notification even when my machine is off)?

I have thought about RDP, but I wanted to have your opinions also.

(PS: FREE Service if it's possible, otherwise the lowest cost)

Thank you!

Comment: i know one. pythonanywhere does it and they have free beginner account else it is the hacker account for $5 per month. Unfortunately the beginner account is restricted outbound Internet.

Comment: Good, I will take the Hacker account on my considerations, thank you for your reply))

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to setup AWS EC2 instance with whatever OS you want.

For beginner, you can get 750 hours of usage for free where you can run your script on.